# Quickblox: Unable to get push Notifications with FCM getting errr 401

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, quickblox, http-status-code-401

I want to implement push notification in app by FCM.
The app is successfully getting FCM pushnotification but when i want to send from Quickblox admin pannel then that give me error like

> error_description":"Unable to deliver notification 20860148, received error 401 (Unauthorized, check your App auth_key.)

This is log.json file :-

```
{"notification":{"registration_ids":["dA_lOjHQU2M:APA91bHB0zGuoalZoxtdcstBQ0dL0pPJA5HyUaoPVibD2iqnrUA51NLqrrmY5zrTZV7OaP55nUEber9NLkPs_ENkVtHLvbEAcHTrgh8wl_YoNhRsUNdyeIWt0mPDKk0tCDyLssXRuFu8"],"delay_while_idle":false,"data":{"message":"hii tesas","collapse_key":"event12616627"},"priority":"high","time_to_live":86400},"
```

> log":[{"device_token":null,"created_at":"2016-12-14T09:56:50Z","delivered_at":null,"failed_at":"2016-12-14T09:56:51Z","error_code":401,"error_description":"Unable to deliver notification 20860148, received error 401 (Unauthorized, check your App auth_key.)"}]}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are required to put Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) API key in your Quickblox Admin panel. Make sure you put Google Server Key there.

Follow these steps to get the server key:

1. Log into Google api console https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/
2. Go to "Credentials" in the navigation on the left side.
3. There you should have your Server Key.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Because of GCM deprecate now so You are required to put Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) API Server key in your Quickblox Push notification panel go to setting and paste FCM Server key in Android-> Develpment or Production. Make sure you put Firebase Server Key there.

Follow these steps to get the server key:

Log into Firebase console https://console.firebase.google.com/
Add your project or select your project if you are already added
now click on setting icon go to project setting -> cloud messaging. there you can find your server key copy that key and paste in

[image]

There you should have your Server Key.
Hope this helps!